# I can not download any app from App Store on my Mac Pro (Mid 2012) Mojave

Tags: mojave, mac-appstore, software-update, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro running a fresh install of **macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G4032)**

I have no issues login into any service in iCloud, iTunes, App Store, all good
but when I try to update (the apple office-package) or download any other app it simply does not work

I did try to logout-login, flush the DNS, Delete the app-store cache, restart the router, different recommendations from the internet, nothing works

**It shows, I have 3 updates**

[image: it shows I have 3 updates]

**it used to show the apps that need to be updated, but it does not**
[image]

**Nothing happens when I click on download**
[image]

**the loading animation just animates, there is no download happening**
[image]

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54441/how-to-remove-an-app-stuck-in-waiting-mode-from-the-mac-app-store

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54441/how-to-remove-an-app-stuck-in-waiting-mode-from-the-mac-app-store https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/391725/app-store-on-mojave-we-could-not-complete-your-purchase-cancelled